# alpineJS state in Laravel named route function

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

Im trying to use alpineJs state to create my href url but with using Laravel named routes.

```
<div x-data="{ selectedSession: '{{$sessionsForDay->first()->id}}' }">
...
   <select id="session" name="session" x-on:change="$dispatch('selection-change', { value: $event.target.value })">

      @foreach($sessionsForDay as $sesson)
         <option @if ($loop->first) Selected @endif value="{{ $session->id }}">Session Name</option>
      @endfor

   </select>  
   
   <a 
    x-data="{ url: '{{ route('tours.booking', ['session_id' => $sessionsForDay->first()->id]) }}',  selectedSession: '{{ $sessionsForDay->first()->id }}' }"
    href="{{ route('tours.booking', ['session_id' => $sessionsForDay->first()->id]) }}" 
    x-on:selection-change.document="
    url = url.replace(selectedSession, $event.detail.value);
    selectedSession = $event.detail.value;"
    x-bind:href="url">
        Book Now
    </a>
```

Code is currently working when the $session->id is high above 10ish, but below it will just crash. No error in console. just the url will stay the first url on load but only after I select afew other sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using dynamic variables as replaces for an url.
Instead, use a placeholder:

```html
<a 
    x-data="{ baseUrl: '{{ route('tours.booking', ['session_id' => ':sessionId']) }}', url: {{ route('tours.booking', ['session_id' => $sessionsForDay->first()->id]) }}, selectedSession: '{{ $sessionsForDay->first()->id }}' }"
    href="{{ route('tours.booking', ['session_id' => $sessionsForDay->first()->id]) }}" 
    x-on:selection-change.document="
    url = baseUrl.replace(':sessionId', $event.detail.value);
    selectedSession = $event.detail.value;"
    x-bind:href="url">
        Book Now
</a>
```